# Fastest way to join coulmn values in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, large-data

**Problem:**

Given a large data set (3 million rows x 6 columns) what's the fastest way to join values of columns in a single pandas data frame, based on the rows where the mask is true?

**My current solution:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
  
# Note: Real data will be 3 millon rows X 6 columns,
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['0', '1', '2', '3'],
               'msg': ['msg0', 'msg1', 'msg0', 'msg2'],
               'd0': ['a', 'x', 'a', '1'],
               'd1': ['b', 'x', 'b', '2'],
               'd2': ['c', 'x', np.nan, '3']})
#print(df)

msg_text_filter = ['msg0', 'msg2']
columns = df.columns.drop(df.columns[:3])
column_join = ["d0"]

mask = df['msg'].isin(msg_text_filter)

df.replace(np.nan,'',inplace=True)
# THIS IS SLOW, HOW TO SPEED UP?
df['d0'] = np.where(
    mask,
    df[['d0','d1','d2']].agg(''.join, axis=1),
    df['d0']
)
df.loc[mask, columns] = np.nan

print(df)
```

Comment: Pandas is good for many things. As long as they fit in memory. Relational databases are good at many things, including indexing and storing more rows than you have room in RAM for. You may find that a sql JOIN is the most natural solution to address your throughput concerns. Of course, for CSV files, there's always awk + sort + /usr/bin/join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you can save a lot of time by using

```py
df[['d0', 'd1', 'd2']].sum(axis=1)
```

instead of

```py
df[['d0', 'd1', 'd2']].agg(''.join, axis=1)
```

And I think instead of using `np.where` you could just do:

```py
df.loc[mask, 'd0'] = df.loc[mask, ['d0', 'd1', 'd2']].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Timus, this speed up the filter operation from about 35 seconds to 8 seconds. It also is much easier to read. I did have to make some modifications such as replacing all the np.nan values with ' ' before filtering, or else the result would be 0.0.